# How to get the true colors of an android:icon to show through in a Button

Tags: android, button, icons, drawable, xml-drawable

I'm using this code:

```xml
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:icon="@drawable/pause"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.Icon"/>
```

And here's my icon's XML drawable code:

```xml
<vector android:height="1000dp" android:viewportHeight="48"
    android:viewportWidth="48" android:width="1000dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#0883d9" android:pathData="M20,24H10V8c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h6c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2V24z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#0370c8" android:pathData="M18,42h-6c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2V24h10v16C20,41.1 19.1,42 18,42z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#0883d9" android:pathData="M38,24H28V8c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h6c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2V24z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#0370c8" android:pathData="M36,42h-6c-1.1,0 -2,-0.9 -2,-2V24h10v16C38,41.1 37.1,42 36,42z"/>
</vector>
```

But all I see is a white icon, like this:
[image: Picture of button]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is due to the default styling of the **Widget.Material3.Button.Icon** in Material Design 3. This style applies a tint to the icon, which is why your icon is appearing as white.

To fix this, you can override the **iconTint** attribute to **null** in your button's style, so that the original color of your drawable is used. Here's how you can do it:

Firstly, in your styles.xml, define a new style that inherits from **Widget.Material3.Button.Icon** and overrides the **iconTint** attribute:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.Icon">
    <item name="android:iconTint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then, use this style in your button:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/play_pause_button"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:icon="@drawable/pause"
   android:textAlignment="center"
   style="@style/MyButtonStyle"/>
```

With this change, your button should display the icon in its original colors.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT.

Comment: Also, it contains a mistake (null instead of @null) and doesn't do anything.